# I need to create a Microsoft Word Macro to automatically resize images to a pixel width

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm building a macro library for a report set, but in many cases, the images I show as examples in the report need to be resized to one of the following pixel widths:

- 300px
- 400px
- 500px
- 600px
- 700px

I tried creating a macro that changes the exact width of each image by pixel width, but it seems to ignore the aspect ratio and stretch the image.  Is it possible to lock the aspect ratio with a macro?

Realistically all I want is a very short macro that resizes the width of the image by [X] pixels and does nothing else - but, as with any other resize macro, I keep getting the height weirdness.

Is there a resize macro language for ONLY by pixel width?

---

This is the percent sizing code example I've been working from:

```
Sub FNG_setsize75percent()
'
' FNG_setsize75percent Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^g"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    Dim PercentSize As Integer
     PercentSize = 75
     If Selection.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
         Selection.InlineShapes(1).ScaleHeight = PercentSize
         Selection.InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth = PercentSize
     Else
         Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight Factor:=(PercentSize / 100), _
           RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoCTrue
         Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth Factor:=(PercentSize / 100), _
           RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoCTrue
     End If

    End With
    Selection.InlineShapes(1).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
End Sub
```

Now, if I can actually use something similar, my GUESS is that I can use something akin to this:

```
Sub Img500px
    Selection.InlineShapes(1).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    Selection.InlineShapes(1).Width = 375#
    Selection.InlineShapes(1).Height = (Selection.InlineShapes(1).AbsoluteWidth / 375#) * Selection.InlineShapes(1).Height

End Sub
```

Except for one small problem: It still doesn't work.

```
Sub Img500px
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^g"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
     Selection.InlineShapes(1).Width = 375#
     Selection.InlineShapes(1).Height = (Selection.InlineShapes(1).Width / 375#) * Selection.InlineShapes(1).Height

     End With
     Selection.InlineShapes(1).LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

End Sub
```

This doesn't work either.

So while "it's a simple math thing" may seem to fix it, it's still not working as intended.

It's really simple:

500 pixels / inches / whatever
Lock Aspect Ratio, resize height according to aspect ratio.

I agree this should be a "simple math problem" but the code still ain't doin' what you sez it's supposed to be doin'.

Of course I may just go with an external macro program rather than try to futz with this any longer.

Comment: What exactly is "the same issue that shows up when you try to set each one by percentage"?  It's not clear from your post exactly what the problem is.  Also, it would help to post the code you have, even if it's not working exactly as you want.

Comment: If you record a macro using the built-in macro functions and tell it to resize the image by [X] pixels, it doesn't follow the LockAspectRatio code - IE, it'll resize it, but it will leave the height alone and skew the image size.

For example, with the image selected:

Record Macro> ContextualMenuButton-FormatPicture > Size > AbsoluteWidth_setto500px_taboutoffield-Keep Lock Aspect Ratio Checked > OK

SHOULD, theoretically, set the selected image to a width of 500pixels with a locked aspect ratio - so regardless of what image I'm sizing it'll stay locked aspect.

Comment: So what I want is to basically have a macro that locks the aspect ratio of the selected image, then resizes it to [X] pixels rather than having to right-click each image and resize it manually each time. I have set pixel widths; I just want to make macros for each of those widths WITHOUT having to do the resize via percent, etc. And I don't want to do it globally, because they're all different sizes of images.

Comment: That's the "same issue that shows up when you try to set each by percentage" - that the aspect ratio doesn't lock and the height remains the same regardless of whether you set the aspect ratio to be locked. PITA.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the aspect ratio fixed with a bit of math:

```
Sub Tester()
    ResizeWidth Selection.InlineShapes(1), 200
End Sub

Sub ResizeWidth(s, newWidth As Double)
    s.Height = (s.Width / newWidth) * s.Height
    s.Width = newWidth
End Sub
```

EDIT: this (setting LockAspectRatio) also works for me - the height is automatically adjusted.

```
Sub ResizeWidth(s, newWidth As Double)
    s.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    s.Width = newWidth
End Sub
```

Comment: ...okay, that's great, except that I've run both of these solo and neither is giving me the results I need. In both cases the math isn't the issue. What IS the issue is that I'm running into the blockade of the code. What I need is a macro that does something similar to the following example.